# PyQt5 QWebEngineView displays a white page - Need help troubleshooting

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python application using PyQt5 and QWebEngineView to display a web page. However, I'm encountering an issue where the QWebEngineView is rendering only a white page instead of the expected content from the specified URL.
`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class WebViewWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set the window flags to make it frameless
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Create a central widget for the QMainWindow
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Create a layout for the central widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        # Create a web view using QWebEngineView
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView(self)

        # Set URL for the web view
        self.web_view.setUrl(QUrl("https://some-example"))

        # Add the web view to the layout
        layout.addWidget(self.web_view)

        # Set the initial size of the window
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Capture the initial mouse position when pressed
        self._offsetx = event.x()
        self._offsety = event.y()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Move the window based on mouse movement
        x = event.globalX() - self._offsetx
        y = event.globalY() - self._offsety
        self.move(x, y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and show the main window
    window = WebViewWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

expected content from the specified URL
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBh9O.png)

Comment: try making your Window bigger with self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 800) , could be that your webpage doesnt autoresize so you get only the white part as per your enclosed image

Comment: not working always white page

Comment: try `self.web_view.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(....)` to load an example page from a local  html file to check if it works